# 3750s not logging mac address changes?

Tags: cisco, switch, ios

I have enabled mac address change logging on my Cisco 3750s but I'm not getting any results.

What am I missing? I've moved hardware a couple times and set up a couple new VMs with totally new MAC addresses.

```
logging trap debugging
logging 192.168.X.X

snmp-server enable traps mac-notification change move threshold
mac address-table notification change
mac address-table notification mac-move

interface GigabitEthernetx/0/xx
 switchport access vlan 20
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your SNMP server

```
 snmp-server host 192.168.x.x community_name
```

Logging command is for syslog messages only.